# I am getting 403 error when requesting axios post

Tags: axios, vue-router, vuejs3, laravel-9

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am5Pu.png)I use laravel 9 on the backend, and on the front vue js 3 and vue router.
when trying to make a post request through axios, getting 403 forbidden.
the request does not even reach the controller.
With get requests, there are no such problems.

```
//COMPONENT
store() {
        axios.post('api/articles' , {theme: this.theme, name: this.name, content: this.content, link: this.link})
        .then(res => {

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

problem solved.
the problem was that I sent a post request to Laravel without authorization, but by default, when creating a request class, it has an authorize method that returns false.
in order for the "POST" request to be successfully completed, you must return true in the request class in the authorize method

```
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
```